# How to minimize the browser window in Selenium WebDriver 3

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

After *maximizing* the window by `driver.manage().window().maximize();`, how do I *minimize* the browser window in Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I start a Selenium browser(like Firefox) minimized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643951/how-could-i-start-a-selenium-browserlike-firefox-minimized)

Answer (score 5):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s Java client doesn't have a built-in method to **minimize** the *browsing context*.

However, as the default/common practice is to open the browser in **maximized** mode, while *Test Execution* is *in progress* **minimizing** the browser would be against the best practices as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) may lose the focus over the *browsing context* and an exception may raise during the *test execution*. However, *Selenium's* [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) client does have a [minimize_window()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.minimize_window) method which eventually pushes the *Chrome browsing context* effectively to the background.

---

### Sample code

Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
driver.minimize_window()
```

Java:

```
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
Point p = driver.manage().window().getPosition();
Dimension d = driver.manage().window().getSize();
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point((d.getHeight()-p.getX()), (d.getWidth()-p.getY())));
```

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a [minimize function](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_Window.html#minimize) now:

From the documentation on:

## webdriver.manage().window()

```
this.minimize() → Promise<undefined>
Minimizes the current window. The exact behavior of this command is specific to individual window managers, but typicallly involves hiding the window in the system tray.

Parameters
None.

Returns
Promise<undefined>
A promise that will be resolved when the command has completed.
```

So the code should be:

```
webdriver.manage().window().minimize()
```

At least [in JavaScript](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L1519).

Comment: Thanks for including the "JavaScript" disclaimer. https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWindow.htm says the Minimize function does not exist for .NET Framework developers.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Selenium does not provide any built-in function for minimizing the browser window. There is only the function for maximizing the window. But there is some workaround for doing this.

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-2000, 0));
```

Comment: As mentioned in [DebanjanB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647058/how-to-minimize-the-browser-window-in-selenium-webdriver-3/60379177#60379177), the minimize_window() function works fine from Python. I have used it for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to the minimize browser window. It worked for me and I am using Selenium 3.5:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Selenium WebDriver (Java) 3.4.0 and have not found the minimize function either. Then I'm using the following code.

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, -2000));
```

We need to import the following for the *Point* function.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What is the idea? Move the window off screen?

Answer (score 0):

For C# , tested using Selinium 3.14 ver ( [Package1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/3.141.0?_src=template) , [Package2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.Support/3.141.0?_src=template)) and it work

```
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Manage().Window.Minimize();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium version 4, there is a method called `minimize()` added in Window interface (An inner interface of WebDriver) with Java.
Hence now, if you have Selenium version 4, then you can use `driver.manage().window().minimize()`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Python.

The window will open and after loading it will minimize.

```py
driver.get(url)
driver.minimize_window()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It should work.

```
Dimension n = new Dimension(360, 592);  
driver.manage().window().setSize(n);
```