# How to minimize or hide the Geckodriver in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, minimize

This is what I have:

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

How can I let the [geckodriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LYuH.png) open minimized or hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the firefox driver options to headless so that it opens minimized. Here is the code to do that.

```
fireFoxOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
fireFoxOptions.set_headless()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=fireFoxOptions)
```

If this doesn't work for you there are other methods that you can use. Check out this other SO question for those: [How to make firefox headless programmatically in Selenium with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python)

Comment: I am saying the geckodriver, not the browser.

Comment: Then what do you mean by 'open geckodriver minimized' - geckodriver is what communicates with the Firefox browser. I'm not sure I understand what you want to do by minimizing a driver, can you clarify?

Comment: Well, I want to let the user unable to see the browser and the driver, and I already have the answer to hide the browser.

Answer (score 0):

### geckodriver

[geckodriver](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/) in it's core form is a *proxy* for using W3C WebDriver-compatible clients to interact with Gecko-based browsers.

This program provides the HTTP API described by the [WebDriver protocol](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#protocol) to communicate with Gecko browsers, such as Firefox. It translates calls into the [Firefox remote protocol](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/marionette/Protocol.html#protocol) by acting as a proxy between the local- and remote ends.

So more or less it acts like a service. So the question to minimize the *GeckoDriver* shouldn't arise.

---

### *Minimizing Mozilla Firefox browser*

The [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) initiated [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) *Browsing Context* by default opens in semi **maximized** mode. Perhaps while executing tests with the *browsing context* being **minimized** would be against all the best practices as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) may loose the focus over the *Browsing Context* and an exception may raise during the *Test Execution*.

However, *Selenium's* [python](/questions/tagged/python) client does have a [minimize_window()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.minimize_window) method which eventually minimizes the *Chrome Browsing Context* effectively.

---

### Solution

You can use the following solution:

- *Firefox*:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
  options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
  driver.minimize_window()
  ```
- *Chrome*:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
  driver.minimize_window()
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed relevant discussion in:

- [How to Minimize browser window in selenium webdriver 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647058/how-to-minimize-browser-window-in-selenium-webdriver-3/60379177#60379177)

---

### tl; dr

[How to make firefox headless programmatically in Selenium with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243)

Comment: I am saying the geckodriver, not the browser.

Comment: @JohnIson You should have commented replying to my comment to your question, not as a comment to my answer. please delete this comment.

Comment: @JohnIson Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @JohnIson There isn't any significant difference. The code block I have provided with in my answer is provided to provide a clear picture to the future readers who ever steps in.

Comment: GeckoDriver is a service, are you able to see the geckodriver service really?