# How to hide the firefox browser in selenium c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I have been using the selenium to find text from web page.In that function when i run it opens firefox in foreground. I don't want it to be in foreground. Is there any way to hide that browser.

I have developed this in classlibrary project using xUnit.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017322/how-to-minimize-or-hide-the-geckodriver-in-selenium/63017936#63017936) help you?

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB.It helped me

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily by using this,

```
options.AddArgument("headless");
```

and then,

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying,I have used this code.But browser is showing at once and then hiding.I don't want it to be in foreground.It should be totally in background.

Comment: use this at the top of your code, i mean before the get request....

Comment: Ok i will try that.